# Animate Position Change As Div Floats Left

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a bunch of divs that live inside a container. When a user clicks on one of them they are removed and a divs below that one slide over to fill the space it left because they are set to `float:left` like this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xrejeewf/). I want the divs to animate as they move over to fill the space. Is there a CSS or jQuery function to automatically do that, or would I have to calculate the position each div is currently in and then call some kind of `animateAll()` to move them to the position that they will be?

Comment: see this http://jsfiddle.net/CUzNx/87/

Comment: Check this link:-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26953173/how-to-animate-the-position-change-or-float-left-on-window-size-change

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `$(this).addClass('hide').fadeOut(500, function() { $(this).remove(); });` to hide and remove that child after transition

**demo:-**

```js
$("div").click(function(){
 $(this).addClass('hide').fadeOut(500, function() { $(this).remove(); });
});
```

```css
div {
  float:left;
  height:20px;
  width:20px;
  margin:5px;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}
div:hover {
  cursor:pointer;
}
.hide {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="background:red;"></div>
<div style="background:orange;"></div>
<div style="background:yellow;"></div>
<div style="background:green;"></div>
<div style="background:blue;"></div>
<div style="background:purple;"></div>
```

[Check this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xrejeewf/7/)

Comment: this also nice one

Answer (score 0):

Please check this script.

```
    $("div").click(function(){
$(this).css('opacity',0).animate({
    width: 0,
  }, 1000, function() {
    $(this).remove();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 $("#divname").click(function(){
    $("div").animate({"width":"0px"}, "slow",function() {
     $(this).remove();
  });
 });
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use jquery animate

```
 $("div").click(function(){
        $(this).remove();
        $("div").animate({"left":"0px"}, "slow")
    });
```